# Any HTML-element with display style "inline-block" as it's default?

Tags: html

SPAN elements have by default display type "inline". DIV elements have "block". But are there any container elements with "inline-block" as it's default display style?

UPDATE:
I look for "container-only" elements that are not input controls or image.

Answer (score 1):

`img`, `button`, `textarea`, `input`, and select are all `inline-block`

You can have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vgyxs/3/

Comment: Are there any container-only elements (I have updated my question) ?